# How Do I Align Views Within A VStack In A Frame In SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have a 'tile' that displays three things. A photo of the product, the title of the product and type of product (see photo). When the title of the product is longer, the photo is pushed up and made smaller as expected. I need to make the title and type of product go lower down in the frame so the photo can be the main focus. I am unsure how to achieve this.

Here is the code for this view:

```
 VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
                    
                    WebImage(url: URL(string: productData.product_profileImage))
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .clipped()
                        .padding(5)
               
                    Text(productData.product_name)
                    .font(.title2)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .padding()

                    
                Text(productData.product_type)
                    .font(.caption)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .lineLimit(2)
                    .padding()
            }
                .frame(width: 150, height: 200)
```

Here is a photo of what it currently looks like:
[image: how it looks]

Answer (score 1):

Give a higher layout priority to image, so it would lay out first and keep all needed space, like

```
WebImage(url: URL(string: productData.product_profileImage))
    .resizable()
    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
    .clipped()
    .padding(5)
    .layoutPriority(1)     // << here !!
```

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

Comment: This sorts the photo issue! However after doing this, the text has got much smaller, is there a way around this?

Comment: Well, you need to give more space for text, like remove extra padding, give smaller font size, etc. Give a .border for each element and you'll see where you loose space.

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve it by wrapping your Text content in a separate `VStack`.

```
VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
        
        WebImage(url: URL(string: productData.product_profileImage))            
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .clipped()
            .padding(5)
        
        VStack { //Wrap your text content into VStack
            Text("Example Product A")
                .font(.title2)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .padding()
            
            
            Text("Clothing")
                .font(.caption)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                .lineLimit(2)
                .padding()
        }

}.frame(width: 150, height: 200)
```

Comment: This sorts the photo issue! However after doing this, the text has got much smaller, is there a way around this?

Comment: you can change the value inside the method of  `minimumScaleFactor()` to adjust the text scale.